# Returning IEnumerable from Repository using ToList() vs using IList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, repository-pattern

**Update 3/31/2017**

I've learned a few more things since this post, so want to give one important reason to use `ToList` when returning from the repository - calling `ToList` will (when using IQueryable) execute the translated SQL on the database instead of pulling records into memory and then filtering. I don't believe the implicit cast to IEnumerable or IList does this.

---

Following some of the tutorials on the MSDN website, I have utilized the generic repository layer in my application. This repository layer is called by my service layer, which is in turn called by the controller.

Looking at the generic repository, the data is fetched and is returned by calling `ToList()`. However, the return type of the method is `IEnumerable` which means the service layer must accept `IEnumerable` and before returning to the controller it must **once again** call a `ToList()` on the `IEnumerable`.

**Example - Repository:**

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = "")
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    return orderBy != null ? orderBy(query).ToList() : query.ToList();
}
```

**Example - Service Layer**

```
public IList<DOC> SearchDocuments(string docInfo)
{
    // build the predicate and logic, etc

    // grab all the matching documents with the relationships
    IEnumerable<DOC> documents = _unitOfWork.DocumentRepository.Get(
        predicate,
        p => p.OrderBy(d => d.DocInfo),
        "DocRelationship, DocRelationship.OtherDocTable");

    return documents.ToList();
}
```

From the reading that I've done, it seems to be best to simply present to the controller a `List` of objects that it needs versus an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`.

Therefore, I think it would be better to instead of returning an `IEnumerable`to return an `IList` instead. Am I missing something here - why did the MSDN team choose `IEnumerable` for the design and call `ToList`? Where would this be useful?? In my eyes it seems to be inefficient and pointless to do that conversion more than once, especially if dealing with a large set of data.

I apologize in advance if this is not clear or there is already an answer, but I have been searching and reading the other posts IEnumerable vs IQueryable vs IList, but I still do not understand this particular issue.

Comment: They are different types/interfaces and the semantics are different in Entity Framework (calling `ToList()` on an `IQueryable` materializes the query at that point, so if you have further refinements on the query, they're being done in-memory rather than in the database).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Return minimal interface that works *for your particular case*.

Often `IEnumerable<T>` is enough and give more flexibility, but if you see yourself need to use `.ToList()` often (and for valid reasons) return `IList<T>` or even `List<T>`.

Notes

- `IEnumerable<T>` allows much easier lazy evaluation and unit testing (since it is smaller than `IList` - so try to stick with it.
- your sample does not show valid reasons to call `.ToList()` - combining `IEnumerable<T>` till you know what exactly you are looking for may even get you better performance (i.e. if after several checks you decide you need just one element but `ToList` will force you to fetch 10000).

Comment: What would be considered a valid reason to use `IList` or `List`?

Comment: @Cody Typically, a good approach is to use IList<T> in your public facing API (when appropriate, and list semantics are needed), and then List<T> internally to implement the API.  This allows you to change to a different implementation of IList<T> without breaking code that uses your class.

Comment: So, in my repository layer - should I instead be using something like `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` to return that `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @Cody Personally in your case I would return IEnumerable from your repository layer. You have no reason to use ToList in the code provided IMO

Comment: Good points! One more reason to why I stick with IEnumerable<T> over IList<T> is that we use Composite and Specification pattern, and to se the whole query, letting it return a IQueryable is an easy way for debugging, and then calling ToList on the IQueryable after to actually hit the db.

Answer (score 2):

You're fine. The main thing that is happening right now is that the .ToList() in the repo is actually executing the query against the database. But returning that list as IEnumerable, all you're really doing is boxing it so that the result is generic and unalterable. There's some overhead there to unbox later on but since the duty of the repository is to return the REQUESTED data, you should return it like this imo.

I think this is probably what the team was thinking. You asked for this data, so here it is. If you need to do further editing on it, you'll have to enumerate it again in order to make any modifications to that list. There's nothing wrong with that. In fact, it supports SoC.

Typically, my repos return IEnumerable, then if my service layer needs to return something like a dto or viewmodel, I'll use that IEnum to build the new object:

```
var myEnumerable = _uow.MyJunk.Get(j => j.Stuff.Where(a => a.OtherJunk == something);
var myDtos = myEnumerable.Select(obj => new DtoClass { Foo = obj.Foo, Bar = obj.Bar };
return myDtos;
```

Comment: What "boxing" you are talking about? You may mean something different, but it reads as you are somehow refer to boxing of value types...

Comment: My fault. I really couldn't think of another term for returning something as it's interface. I see how "boxing" could be misleading to some.

Comment: To clarify, I really just meant casting, but it's harder to incorporate "this as that" into a descriptive sentence while conveying the real idea.